# Controlling page view scroll when CircularProgressBar is shown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to control the page view scroll when progress bar is showing in flutter.

creating a page with 100 pages and each scroll I am making API call and showing the data. During the API call progress bar is shown using future builder.

My requirement/issue is users are able to scroll even when the API call is happening. Please let me know how to control. As per my understanding changing the physics based on some flag won't work because it needs the Boolean to be changed using set state, that cause full rebuild of the widget.

The problem is scroll happens when progress bar is visible.

Comment: *"My requirement/issue is users are able to scroll even when the API call is happening."* - and what do you have problems with?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem :-)

Comment: @intraector showing progress bar mean something is happening so that time scroll should not happen. It should happen only when the progress bar is dismissed